# Dropdown hiding behind Revolution Slider in Wordpress

Tags: slider

My dropdown menu is hiding behind my Revolution Slider in Wordpress here:

http://testenvironment1.rawweb.com.au/

I have tried playing with the z-index and overflow:hidden properties in a variety of different locations but cannot seem to fix the issue.

CSS file is here: http://testenvironment1.rawweb.com.au/wp-content/themes/duena/style.css

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your Problem solved???? I'm also having same issues.